# Python: is it possible to launch a process with a certain PID?

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to launch a subprocess using `subprocess.Popen()`.

Is it possible to assign a predetermined PID to that process?

Comment: What ID do you mean? The Process ID ("PID")?

Comment: Impossible. The OS assigns the PID. Some operating systems (OpenBSD, maybe others) actually assign *randomized* PIDs for security reasons.

Comment: You actually _might_ be able to do it, from userspace by calling the right lower-level APIs (and, if not, you can always write a kernel module that exposes the right lower-level APIs). Obviously this would be very platform-specific… And probably not very easy. (For example, on OS X you'd probably have to create a process using pure Mach before you can map it to a BSD process, which is not going to be nearly as easy as calling fork or posix_spawn…)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, PID is assigned by the Operating system -- completely independent of `subprocess`.  (In other words, No, you can't assign it -- at least not in any system independent way and without working at it extremely hard).  You can get the [child process's PID](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid) from `Popen` if that helps you at all...

Comment: while that is true, nothing is impossible. if this is question of life and death, you can do it on kernel level, maybe not with python though. what im saying, if OS assigns PID, you can intercept that process.